# Creating a Push Button that performs a function

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, listener, jbutton

I ended up simplifying my approach greatly. I just modified the second class file to for the button and got rid of the third entirely. Now both the action button and pressing the return key on the keyboard cause the program to complete the calculation. It really wasn't difficult, just required using the same approach but with a different type of listener.  Thank you!

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Fahrenheit
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Fahrenheit");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    FahrenheitPanel panel = new FahrenheitPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class FahrenheitPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel, resultLabel;
    private JTextField fahrenheit;
    private JButton push;

    public FahrenheitPanel()
    {
        inputLabel = new JLabel ("Enter Fahrenheit temperature:");
        outputLabel = new JLabel ("Temperature in Celsius: ");
        resultLabel = new JLabel ("---");
        push = new JButton ("Convert");

        fahrenheit = new JTextField (5);
        fahrenheit.addActionListener (new TempListener());
        push.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());

        add (inputLabel);
        add(fahrenheit);
        add (outputLabel);
        add (resultLabel);
        add (push);

        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300,75));
        setBackground (Color.yellow);
    }


    private class TempListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {
            int fahrenheitTemp, celsiusTemp;

            String text = fahrenheit.getText();

            fahrenheitTemp = Integer.parseInt (text);
            celsiusTemp = (fahrenheitTemp-32) * 5/9;

            resultLabel.setText (Integer.toString (celsiusTemp));
          }
      }


    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {
            int fahrenheitTemp, celsiusTemp;

            String text = fahrenheit.getText();

            fahrenheitTemp = Integer.parseInt (text);
            celsiusTemp = (fahrenheitTemp-32) * 5/9;

            resultLabel.setText (Integer.toString (celsiusTemp));           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but the third is where I need some guidance"*  Umm.. 'Ask a question'.  How's that for guidance?  Also, for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Good point. Will do next time. Thank you for the link as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following things to implement it.

1. Define a variable of type in class PushCounterPanel , like

   **private  FahrenheitPanel panel;**

   And Change the constructor of class PushCounterPanel .

   public  PushCounterPanel ( **FahrenheitPanel panel**)
   {
       **this.panel = panel;**
       ... 
   }

To do this, we can get the input text value in Panel FahrenheitPanel.

2  When the Click Button, you need to check if text value is empty and is not numeric first. If numeric values ate enter in text field, then add the following code in class ButtonListener.

```
         fahrenheitTemp = Integer.parseInt(panel.getFahrenheit().getText());
         celsiusTemp = (fahrenheitTemp-32) * 5/9;
```

In this way, you can populate the value by clicking Button.

3  Accordingly, you need to change the following code.

a) main method in Fahrenheit

frame.getContentPane().add(new PushCounterPanel(**panel**));

b) add the following getter/setter method to class FahrenheitPanel.

```
public JTextField getFahrenheit() {
    return fahrenheit;
}


public void setFahrenheit(JTextField fahrenheit) {
    this.fahrenheit = fahrenheit;
```

Hope this can help you some.

Comment: I got it! I'm gonna edit my original post with my solution. Thank you!